# Is it a bad practice to return super.equals and super.hashcode in a class?

Tags: java

Let's say i have this class:

```
public class Person {
    private Integer idFromDatabase;
    private String name;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

The field `idFromDatabase` is the attribute that should be verified in equals and used to create the hashCode. But sometimes, i am working with a list of People in memory, and have not yet stored the objects on the database, so the `idFromDatabase` is null for all objects, which would cause hashCode to return the same value for every object.
I solved this issue by adding the following to equals and hashCode metods:

```
if(idFromDatabase == null) return super.equals(o);
```

and

```
if(idFromDatabase == null) return super.hashCode();
```

It worked, but is it safe? Can i do it for every class that relies on a database field for equality check?

Comment: This will return `false` if you have two separate objects in-memory that aren't retrieved from the database but *should* represent the same object. Is such a situation possible?

Comment: Your class should really be named `Person`, not `People`.

Comment: You're right, but i don't really have this class in my app, this is just an example..

Comment: @MateusViccari That may be, but unless you suddenly switched behavior when posting, you probably name all of your classes that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted by @Jeroen Vannevel, if you are likely to end up with having 2 or more objects not stored in database holding the exact same information, then this technique will not help you in identifying this.

@Solver is also quite true in that a subclass is meant to have different behavior than its superclass, so you shouldn't return that they're equal.

However, in your particular example, you are just extending the `Object` class, so your assumption that it is safe is true (if we exclude the possibility of having 2 not-yet-persisted same `Person`s in memory).

`Object` provides the most basic [equals method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> For any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true 
>   if and only if x and y refer to the same object 
>   (`x == y` has the value `true`).

The [hashCode method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) of Object:

> As much as is reasonably practical, [...] does return distinct integers for distinct objects

These definitions make it clear that if you're only extending `Object`, then this technique is safe.

Answer (score 3):

`if(idFromDatabase == null) return super.equals(o);` is incorrect as super's equals (if implemented correctly) does a `getClass()` check, which will of course be different, thus `super.equals` will always be false.

Comment: Good point. I assume the solution then is to just use `return this == 0` to get that reference equality check.

Answer (score 1):

From your description I'm inferring that when comparing two `People` objects:

- If both have an ID, they are equal if they have the same ID, even if they have different names
- Otherwise, they are only equal if they are the same instance.

If that's correct, then:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (this.idFromDatabase == null)
        return false;
    if (! (obj instanceof People))
        return false;
    People that = (People)obj;
    if (that.idFromDatabase == null)
        return false;
    return this.idFromDatabase.equals(that.idFromDatabase);
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // Use super.hashCode to distribute objects without an idFromDatabase
    return (this.idFromDatabase != null ? this.idFromDatabase.hashCode() : super.hashCode());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your reasoning.

- `equals` and `hashcode` are not subtype-friendly so it doesn't make sense to start thinking about `super` calls,
- `super` is `Object` anyway so it's `equals` and `hashcode` are useless in this context.
- What if you have two `Person` objects referring to the same person, but only one is stored in the database. Are they the same or different?

One universal solution is to make two classes

1. `Person` which stores a 'local' person. Doesn't contain `idFromDatabase`,
2. `StoredPerson` which contains `idFromDatabase` and a `Person` (or all fields of `Person`, but this is harder to maintain)

This way, at least `equals` and `hashcode` are well-defined and well-behaved at all times.

### Implementation and usage

If you use any kind of `Set`/`Map` to store people, you now have two of them. When you save new `Person`s to database, you remove them from the 'local' `Set`/`Map`, wrap them in `StoredPerson`, and put them in the 'database' `Set`/`Map`.

If you want a searchable list of all people, make one with all `Person`s from both datasets into one. When you find a `Person` you're interested in and want to retrieve the `idFromDatabase`, if any, then you'd do good to prepare a map from `Person` to `StoredPerson` beforehand.

Thus you need at least,

```
Set<Person> localPeople = new HashSet<>();
Map<Person, StoredPerson> storedPeople = new HashMap<>();
```

and something like this:

```
void savePerson(Person person) {
    synchronized (lockToPreserveInvariants) {
        int id = db.insert(person);

        StoredPerson sp = new StoredPerson(id, person);

        localPeople.remove(person);
        storedPeople.put(person, sp);
    }
}
```